# How to replace body background at smaller resolutions

Tags: css, html, less

I have a blog template which I'm making responsive, how can i change the background of the body at smaller resolutions, I'm trying the following but it doesn't work.

```
@media (max-width: 30em) {

  .post-template {
    background-color: @color_01;
  }
}
```

my body has the class

```
<body class="post-template">
```

The MixIn which applies the body color styling is as follows

```
.BodyColor () {
background-color: @color_01;
background-image: url(../images/body.jpg);
color: @color_05;
overflow-x: hidden;
background-attachment: fixed;
&:after {
content: ' ';
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
background-color: darken(@color_01, 10%);
.transform(~"skew(-20deg) rotate(-20deg)");
left: 0;
top: 30%;
.opacity(0.5);
position: fixed;
}
```

}

I want to overwrite the .transform call, so there isn't a skew on smaller resolutions as it renders too slowly

however I've set some properties of the `body:after`pseudo class which I want to overwrite at smaller resolutions.

Comment: use px not em in the media query and what is `@color_01`?

Comment: typo, editing now. @Chimoo `@color_01 is a less variable, assigned a hex value in variables.less

Comment: is your LESS working?

Comment: yes. LESS is working.

Comment: does it work if you change it to `@media (max-width: 5000px) {`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 30em) {
  .post-template {
    background-color: @big_size_color;
  }
  .post-template:after {
    yourcode...
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 30em) {
  .post-template {
    background-color: @color_01;
  }
}
```

This keeps the `body:after` code from being shown unless the page is bigger than 30em.  This rule applies to anything you want to only work on higher resolutions and be "overridden" on smaller ones.  Don't declare it by itself outside of the `@media` call.